# "View Based content mode on OS X versions prior to 10.7"

Tags: xcode, cocoa, interface-builder

`View Based content mode on OS X versions prior to 10.7`

`Identifier on OS X versions prior to 10.7`

This comes up as a warning when trying to use the "Source List" object in IB. My build target is set to 10.6 for development/release and it does build.

Would I be right as to assume this would actually crash in 10.6? Why does it let me even build it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look immediately above the warning in the Issues Navigator, you'll find that it's under a heading named something like “Unsupported Attribute”.

So the *full* warnings, including the heading that is meant to go along with them, are:

> - Unsupported attribute: View Based content mode on OS X versions prior to 10.7
> - Unsupported attribute: Identifier on OS X versions prior to 10.7

In other words, it's telling you that the “View Based content mode” and “Identifier” attributes are not supported on OS X versions prior to 10.7.

The problem isn't that the table view is a source list; that was introduced in 10.5. The problem is that:

- You have given the table view (or something in it) an identifier, and
- You have created the table view as a view-based table view.

Of course, the main reason to give anything in a table view an identifier is for view reuse, so these are really one problem.

#### Solution/TL;DR

You're trying to use a view-based table view in an app for 10.6. That won't work. You need to either require 10.7 (or later) or make a cell-based table view.